# Can I add an instance declaration in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, ghci

I was messing around with `HashMap` and tried to use a `Data.Bson.ObjectId` as a key.  I, of course, discovered that there is not a `Hashable` instance for that structure.  That's ok, because writing one is trivial.<sup>1</sup>

```
instance Hashable ObjectId where hash (Oid x y) = hash (x,y)
```

I typed that line into GHCi and was told "parse error on input `instance'".  This actually makes sense as the GHCi prompt operates as if the lines were being typed into a do block in the IO monad and an instance can not be defined in this context.

My question then, is there a way to define a new instance within GHCi?

---

<sup>1</sup> Why this instance is not provided by the library is another matter. I would believe the answer was to limit dependencies except that the bson package already depends on everything under the sun.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The good news:** Yes, there is a way to define a new instance within GHCi.

**The bad news:** At the moment, the first step in doing so is "install a development snapshot of GHC".

This has been an obvious bit of missing functionality in GHCi for quite a while. There was no inherent reason for it to be absent, but I assume it was somewhat difficult to implement and so it got set aside.

However, it seems that [as of version 7.4.1, it's now available](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/dist/current/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-decls):

> At the GHCi prompt you can also enter any top-level Haskell declaration, including data, type, newtype, class, instance, deriving, and foreign declarations. For example:
>
> ```
> Prelude> data T = A | B | C deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Enum)
> Prelude> [A ..]
> [A,B,C]
> Prelude> :i T
> data T = A | B | C      -- Defined at <interactive>:2:6
> instance Enum T -- Defined at <interactive>:2:45
> instance Eq T -- Defined at <interactive>:2:30
> instance Ord T -- Defined at <interactive>:2:34
> instance Show T -- Defined at <interactive>:2:39
> ```

Whether you think having that right now worth the hassle of installing a non-release version of GHC is up to you.